# problema Javascript número 2 y 3 cifras

Tags: javascript, split

¿Qué debería tocar del siguiente código para que al introducir un número de 3 cifras, y otro de 2 (por ejemplo 100,12) me pinte en pantalla al igual que lo hace con un solo número?

Cuando introduzca letra, el programa debe seguir pidiendo obviamente el nº de filas y columnas.

```js
do {
var numero=prompt("¿Número de filas y columnas? (ej: 2 6)");

numero.split(",");
var columna=parseInt(numero[2]);
var filas=parseInt(numero[0]);

}while(isNaN(columna,filas))

document.write("<table border='1'>");
for(var i=1; i<=filas; i++) {
 document.write("<tr>");
 for(var j=1; j<=columna;j++) {
  document.write("<td> Celda" + i+ "-" +j+ " "+ "</td>");
 }
 document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: Obtén el número de filas y columnas asignando  el valor de numero.split(",") a una variable, por ejemplo: var resultado = numero.split(","); , de esta forma "resultado" contendrá los valores que deseas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se produce aquí:

```
var numero=prompt("¿Número de filas y columnas? (ej: 2 6)");

numero.split(",");
var columna=parseInt(numero[2]);
var filas=parseInt(numero[0]);
```

Si introduces por ejemplo:

```
100,12
```

en realidad `numero` tendrá los siguientes valores:

```
numero[0] > 1
numero[1] > 0
numero[2] > 0
numero[3] > ,
numero[4] > 1
numero[5] > 2
```

En este caso determina que tiene que generar 0 columnas y 1 fila ¿? :-\, lo cual es incorrecto.

```
var columna=parseInt(numero[2]); //Valor 0
var filas=parseInt(numero[0]); //Valor 1
```

---

Primeramente, ya que usas `split(",")`, cambia el mensaje a :

```
var numero=prompt("¿Número de filas y columnas? (ej: 2,6)");
```

Ahora **el resultado de `numero.split(",")` almacenarlo en una variable y de esta forma podrás obtener el número de columnas y filas que define el usuario**:

```
var resultado = numero.split(",");

var filas=parseInt(resultado[0]);
var columna=parseInt(resultado[1]);
```

Revisa el código:

```js
    do {
    var numero=prompt("¿Número de filas y columnas? (ej: 2 6)");

    var resultado = numero.split(",");
       
    var filas=parseInt(resultado[0]);
    var columna=parseInt(resultado[1]);
   

    }while(isNaN(columna,filas))

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    for(var i=1; i<=filas; i++) {
     document.write("<tr>");
     for(var j=1; j<=columna;j++) {
      document.write("<td> Celda" + i+ "-" +j+ " "+ "</td>");
     }
     document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```