# Error Split sobre IP String

Tags: java

Alguien sabría decirme porque este método con el `split()` no devuelve el array correctamente ? Gracias

Mi intención es enviar un String al método que sería una ip y que el método devuelva dicha IP en una array de Strings.

```
public class hola {


    public String[] metoth2 (String a) {
        System.out.println("Ip obtenida");

        System.out.println(a);
        String ip[] = a.split(".");


         System.out.println("Method2Array");
        for (int i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ip[i]);
        }   


        return ip;


    }
```

Clase Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hola text = new Hola();
        String ipS="192.168.12.12";


        String ip[];

        ip=text.metoth2(ipS);

        System.out.println("Printamos ip");

        for (int i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ip[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%c3%b3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%c3%b3mo-utilizar-split)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En Java, si usas el método [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) esta función para expresiones regulares, por lo tanto en el caso de usar el "." debes usar:

```
.split("\\.");
```

en el caso de tu código:

```
String ip[] = a.split("\\.");
```

Esto dice la documentación:

> **[split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)** Divide esta cadena alrededor de coincidencias de la
>   expresión regular dada.

---

A diferencia de `Javascript` donde si puedes usar `.split(".")` sin problema.

Ejemplo:

[problema Javascript número 2 y 3 cifras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/224166/problema-javascript-n%C3%BAmero-2-y-3-cifras/224176#)

Comment: Muchas gracias no habría caido!

Comment: recomiendo la lectura de: el Javadoc sobre la clase [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
y ademas para quitar el "significado especial a un String puede usar: `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(String s)` [mas info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))